# MKAnnotationView error in some devices

Tags: objective-c

I am working on my application, and i am trying to implement a map view with annotations but the problem is its only working on iPhone 4s but not on 5,5s,6 and 6+. I am working on a simulator.

This is the error i am getting:

```
No visible @interface for 'MKPinAnnotationView' declares the selector 'initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:'
```

on this line of code :

```
if (!pinView) {
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annView"];
}
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: so what should i do ? @matt

Comment: i get your point .. ill try to reinstall it thank you ! @matt

Comment: i have no idea .. working on my project without fixing it will try to fix it when i'm done and when i try it on an actual device @matt

Comment: hahaha sure man will let you know @matt

Comment: just found it .. look at the answer @matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it happened to be that this file

```
'/Users/OBSoft/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/23TVEMCQA3T1V/UIKit-2M4VYLEDI34V0.pcm'
```

had to be deleted to get everything working with the simulator.

Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted for solving your problem! Well done. See also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073 I do that a _lot_.